# Regarding the charge configuration on a spherical shell based on the atomic level behavior

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, atomic-physics

With regards to the fundamental theories in Electrostatics, when a **spherical shell** of inner radius $a$ and outer radius $b$ with a $+q$ charge at the center is considered, there will be no electric field lines within the region $a<r<b$. Theoretically, this is agreeable as $Q_{enclosed} = 0$ within this region. 
However, is it possible to understand this phenomenon in a physical aspect? What physical cause (**atomic-level behavior**) blocks these electric field lines entering this region? As I understood, the charge separation at the inner and outer radii of the shell is due to the movement of electrons caused as a result of the attractive and repulsive forces caused by the $+q$ charge at the center, resulting the net enclosed charge to be zero. Yet, I am unable to verify the reason for why these electric field lines cannot enter this region. What **atomic level constraints** are acting on this system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't even need to consider a specific charge in the center. (Reasonably low) static electric fields cannot penetrate any material containing free electrons (i.e. metals). Free electrons, by definition, are free to move if exposed to a force. If you try to put an electric field through such a material, the electric field exerts a force on the electrons, which they follow. This results in the charges collecting at the surface (because usually they don't have enough energy to leave the metal). This process continues until the surface charges completely compensate for the electric field trying to penetrate, resulting in zero field inside the metal.